# how to solve abstract error in calendar gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, calendar

I'm a new android developer
i want to create a grid view calendar
i get my code from this link

> https://github.com/jrdnull/Android-Calendar-GridView-Adapter

when i write this line

```
mGridView.setAdapter(new MonthAdapter(this, mToday[1], mToday[2], metrics);
```

android studio suggest me to implement "onDate" methode.
i don't know what should i do?
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for [MonthAdapter](https://github.com/jrdnull/Android-Calendar-GridView-Adapter/blob/master/MonthAdapter.java) shows it has an abstract method `onDate()`, which means you'll have to implement it if you create an instance.

The purpose of this appears to be to return you information from `getView()` about the `date`, row `position` and row `view`.

As such, your code above should probably look more like this:

```
mGridView.setAdapter(new MonthAdapter(this, mToday[1], mToday[2], metrics) {
    @Override
    protected abstract void onDate(int[] date, int position, View item) {
        //You can probably just leave this empty, or use the data returned here.
    }
});
```

**P.s.** If you just click on the line of code you posted in your question in Android Studio, you should see a red lightbulb appear. Click that and select "implement methods" and it will do this for you.

Comment: yes!!...thanks...when i use implement methods..my code don't use ')' in last line :/..so thanks

Comment: sorry..what is returened position value?

Comment: @Mehrdad_75 Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?